# Infopath promoted fields not available under "Current Item" lookup in SharePoint Designer

Tags: infopath

I have a basic infopath form which I published to Sharepoint. That form has several promoted fields that are shown as columns in my Form library.

For this same form library, I have setup a standard "Publishing Approval" workflow. When attempting to create a custom outgoing e-mail in sharepoint designer, I'd like to have the option to have my custom e-mail show these promoted fields from the form that was submitted.

However, when I click into 'Add or change look-up' after clicking into the defined e-mail Message in SharePoint Designer, and I select "Current Item" as Data Source, it only shows me the default fields under 'Field From Source' (ID, Created By, Modified By, etc).

How do I allow for my promoted fields to be made available that way they appear in the e-mail of the form that was just submitted? I tried doing a look-up from a list but with no success (results returned '0').

Thanks in advance all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a SharePoint guru and I can only give you what I did. It may not be the ideal solution but it is fairly simple for users like me that don't know js. You need to create fields in SharePoint that mirror the fields from the InfoPath form. Use the field types that you want them to be as most of them come over as a single line of text. Then you use workflows to populate those fields from the InfoPath fields. Set you workflows to start when an item is created and when an item is changed. Use the Set field in Current Item Action. I hope that helps!